# How to create page in PHP?

Tags: php

Is there a function in PHP for create page in PHP?
I would something like that:

```
create page("file.php", "<html><body><p>Hello!</p></body></html>");
```

If I run it on `site.it`, It will create site.it/file.php with `<html><body><p>Hello!</p></body></html>`.

Can I do it?

Comment: PHP doesn't have any concept of what we know as a 'page'

Comment: PHP does have a concept of files. And yes, there is a function to create files and specify their contents. However, this is something you should take to Google.

Comment: You can make that function pretty easily. `function create_page ($path, $content) {`...

Comment: PHP is usually meant to construct pages dynamically, not fixate them as plain files.

Comment: *wayyyyyyyyyyyy* too broad a question.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use this function : [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.file-put-contents.php) to create a file and put data into this file

Example :

```
<?php
$file = 'people.txt';
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = file_get_contents($file);
// Append a new person to the file
$current .= "John Smith\n";
// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```